# PHPExcel not downloading in mobile Safari

Tags: php, mobile-safari, phpexcel, xlsx, force-download

I'm using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to generate Excel files on the fly within my PHP application. I'm using the `Excel2007` format.

When a user visits the URL that creates and forces the download of the Excel file, everything works great in all browsers **except for mobile Safari** (iPhone and iPad).

Here are my headers and the `readfile` method:

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file_name . '.xlsx;');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path_to_file . '.xlsx'));
readfile($path_to_file . '.xlsx');
```

When I browse in mobile Safari to the URL that is supposed to download the .xlsx file I can actually see the tabs representing each worksheet of the file, but I don't see the actual data like so:

[image: no output for phpexcel on mobile safari]

Furthermore, there are two additional weird behaviors I'm encountering with this:

- If I download this file on a desktop browser and email it to myself and open it with the Mail app in iOS, the file displays correctly.
- If I then take that attachment from the Mail app in iOS and import into, say, Dropbox, it does NOT display properly (it displays the same as the screenshot above).
- In Chrome, the file downloads properly and opens in Excel or even Numbers as expected, but in the console I see this message: `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.ms-excel:`

Also, per the PHPExcel documentation, in place of `readfile` I have also tried:

```
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

That, however, produces an error in mobile Safari that reads:

```
OfficeImportErrorDomain Error 912
```

To eliminate the `Content-type` as being the issue I've experimented by adjusting the `Content-type` to other values (such as `application/vnd.ms-excel` or even `application/download`). Unfortunately (though not surprisingly) those don't work either.

Any guidance is greatly appreciate.

Comment: Does the headers solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479432/using-header-as-download-link-in-php work? It seems to be a very similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I use `->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')`. Otherwise Safari displays error. 
Although this header makes it to display xlsx file in browser, not downloading. I haven't found any solution to force mobile Safari to download.